# C++ acerca del formato de cadenas de texto salida

Tags: c++

es mi primera pregunta en el foro.

Vengo de un pasado en la programación en C "plain" por decirle de alguna forma.
Ahora tengo instalado un linux mint y estoy usando el g++ para aprender el C++ y un par de libros y tutoriales.

Aquí juega un rol el formato de salida de las cadenas de caracteres y el "ios". 
Tenemos un ios::hex y el método cout.setf() y lo que hago es ésto:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int val = 128;
    cout.setf(ios::hex);
    cout << val << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Me muestra en la salida de la terminal "128" y no 80 como debería ser.
Como hago para mostrar en la consola un número en hexadecimal a través de std::cout?
También me gustaría saber como acotar la salida por ejemplo si muestro 1 byte que muestre "80" y si muestro 2 bytes que muestre "0080".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes que usar el flag `std::ios::basefield`, esto solo mostrara el valor como hexadecimal, para colocar los ceros primero debes establecer un ancho con `std::setw()`, y despues lo rellenamos con `std::setfill('0')`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    int val = 128;
    std::cout.setf(std::ios::hex);
    std::cout << val << std::endl;
    std::cout.setf(std::ios::hex, std::ios::basefield);
    std::cout << val << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setw(4) << val << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(4) << val << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Salida:

```
128
80
  80
0080
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Lo entendí. La cuestión ahora es la de un "sufijo". Por ejemplo si quiero imprimir 80h u 80H como la notación de ensamblador de Intel no sé como se puede hacer de una forma "elegante". Sé que después de la cadena impresa puedo agregar **<< "h"**.
Pero como dije quería saber de alguna forma "elegante".
En C solamente uno le daba por ej. al printf("04Xh") si mal no recuerdo.